# Finding days when users haven't created any entries

Tags: sql

I've 2 tables: users and time_entries, time entries has a foreign key to the users table. Users may create time entries with some time amount in it. I want to write a query which could return summarized amounts of time in arbitrary dates range grouped by user and date - it's easy but I need to include also days when nobody entered any time_entry. I've tried to create an additional table called calendar with dates and left join time_entries to it but I couldn't retrieve a list of users that haven't entered any time_entry. Here is my query:

```
SELECT te.date, SUM(te.amount), user_name
FROM calendar c
         LEFT JOIN time_entries te on c.date = te.date
         RIGHT JOIN asp_net_users anu on te.user_id = anu.id
GROUP BY user_name, te.date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [sticky bit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9661424/sticky-bit) examples I was able to write the following query which solves my problem:

```
SELECT c.date, a.id, COALESCE(sum(te.amount), 0)
FROM asp_net_users a
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT *
                     FROM calendar
                     WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp AND '2019-10-31 00:00:00'::timestamp) c
         LEFT JOIN time_entries te on a.id = te.user_id AND c.date = te.date
WHERE a.department_guid = '95b7538d-3830-48d7-ba06-ad7c51a57191'
GROUP BY c.date, a.id
ORDER BY c.date
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the days no user made any entry. you can use `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT c.date
       FROM calendar c
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM time_entries te
                                WHERE te.date = c.date);
```

If you want all users along with the days they haven't made any entry cross join the users and the days and then also use a `NOT EXISTS`.

```
SELECT anu.user_name,
       c.date
       FROM asp_net_users anu
            CROSS JOIN calendar c
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM time_entries te
                                WHERE te.user_id = anu.id
                                      AND te.date = c.date);
```